# Unable to retrieve secret key from key ring file secring.gpg as it does not exist

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, gnupg

I want to publish my project to maven using `maven-publish` and `signing`. The problem is that when i try to publish: `gradle publish` i get this error:

```
 * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':project:signMavenJavaPublication'.
    > Unable to retrieve secret key from key ring file '/Users/nick/.gnupg/secring.gpg ' as it does not exist
```

Before publishing i generate key as following:

1. gpg --gen-key
2. gpg --export-secret-keys > ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg

Then i change my `~/.gradle.gradle.properties`:

```
signing.keyId=ID
signing.password=PASS
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/nick/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

My gradle.build looks as follows:

```
subprojects {
    if (it.name != 'exclusion') {
        apply plugin: 'java-library'
        apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        apply plugin: 'signing'
    }

    dependencies {
...
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()

        testLogging {
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }

        testClassesDirs = sourceSets.test.output
        classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    }

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        from sourceSets.main.allJava
        archiveClassifier = 'sources'
    }

    task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
        from javadoc
        archiveClassifier = 'javadoc'
    }

    javadoc {
        if(JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible()) {
            options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
        }
    }

    if (it.name != 'exclusion') {
        publishing {
            publications {
                mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                    artifactId = it.name
                    from components.java
                    artifact sourcesJar
                    artifact javadocJar
                    versionMapping {
                        usage('java-api') {
                            fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                        }
                        usage('java-runtime') {
                            fromResolutionResult()
                        }
                    }
                    pom {
...
                        licenses {
...
                        }
                        developers {
...
                        }
                        scm {
...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            repositories {
                maven {
...
                }
            }
        }

        if (project.hasProperty("signing.keyId")) {
            signing {
                sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved this issue by generating not `secring.gpg`, but `secring.kbx`:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys -o ~/secring.kbx
```

I'm not sure that this is the right approach but at least gradle plugin can finally work.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
gpg --keyring secring.gpg --export-secret-keys > ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

More info [here](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring).

Answer (score 0):

The key ring file path should be like this

```
/home/nick/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing that worked was the private key generated by

`gpg --export-secret-keys --export-options backup --output privateKeysBackup.gpg`